# Get custom claims in client application after login cookie issued using Identity Server 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

We are in the process of *learning* Identity Server with the eventual aim of migrating our existing authentication service to it. For company, logistical and compatibility reasons, we are sticking with IS 3. We're not quite ready to move over to Core.

There are two parts to my question:

1) I have modified the sample app, [available here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/CustomLoginPage), that uses a custom login page so that the browser prompts the user for their X509Certificate2 (as a partial login). The user enters a password and the certificate is used to call another endpoint which returns user-specific data. At that point, we wish to create **custom user claims** based on the returned data and then issue the cookie.

This all works fine up until the client receives the cookie. ***I cannot seem to extract the custom claims added to `AuthenticatedLogin`'s `Claims` object on the client application.*** The client is configured to access all scopes.

It seems like I'm missing something very basic. Am I doing something wrong here? Bear in mind, these are just meaningless claims for test purposes.

2) Would this be an acceptable approach to issue claims? We would then likely use the returned cookie in order to call a separate authorisation service, as our roles are quite complex.

I have implemented the custom user service, with `PreAuthenticateAsync` redirecting to the custom login page:

```
 public override Task PreAuthenticateAsync(PreAuthenticationContext context)
 {
     var id = ctx.Request.Query.Get("signin");

     context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult("~/custom/login?id=" + id, (IEnumerable<Claim>)null);
     return Task.FromResult(0);
  }
```

The controller method which creates the claims and calls `IssueLoginCookie` :

```
[RequireHttps]
[Route("core/custom/login")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string id, string password)
{
        var userData = GetUser(password);

        var owinEnvironment = Request.GetOwinContext().Environment;

        var authenticatedLogin = new AuthenticatedLogin
        {
             IdentityProvider = Constants.BuiltInIdentityProvider,
             Name = userData.UserName,
             Subject = userData.EmailAddress, 
             Claims = GetClaims(userData),
             PersistentLogin = false 
        };

        owinEnvironment.IssueLoginCookie(authenticatedLogin);

        var msg = owinEnvironment.GetSignInMessage(id);
        var returnUrl = msg.ReturnUrl;

        owinEnvironment.RemovePartialLoginCookie();

        return Redirect(returnUrl);
  }

  // add our CUSTOM claims
  private List<Claim> GetClaims(CustomUser authenticatedUser)
  {
        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();

        claims.Add(new Claim("claim1", authenticatedUser.CustomClaim1));
        claims.Add(new Claim("claim2", authenticatedUser.CustomClaim2));
        claims.Add(new Claim("claim3", authenticatedUser.CustomClaim3));
        claims.Add(new Claim("Claim4", authenticatedUser.CustomClaim4));

        return claims;
  }
```

The client controller method with `Authorize` decorator:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult About()
{
    // "CustomClaim1", "CustomClaim2" etc are not there :( 
    return View((User as ClaimsPrincipal).Claims);
}
```

The registered in-memory scope:

```
var scope1 = new Scope
{
     Enabled = true,
     Name = "user",
     Type = ScopeType.Identity,
     Claims = new List<ScopeClaim>
     {
         new ScopeClaim("CustomClaim1", true),
         new ScopeClaim("CustomClaim2", true),
         new ScopeClaim("CustomClaim3", true),
         new ScopeClaim("CustomClaim4", true),
     },

     IncludeAllClaimsForUser = true
  };
```

And finally the client's `Configuration`:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
            AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = Constants.ClaimTypes.Subject;
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "https://localhost/idprov/core",
                ClientId = "mvc",
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost/dummyclient/About",
                ResponseType = "id_token",
                ClientSecret = "secret",
                Scope = "openid partyuser",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try adding scope in your client like

```
 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://localhost/idprov/core",
            ClientId = "mvc",
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost/dummyclient/About",
            ResponseType = "id_token",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            Scope = "openid partyuser CustomClaim1 CustomClaim2",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
        });
```